# Using Anonymous Versus Member Functions

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I was working with `CompletableFutures` when I ran in to situation. Let's say I wanted to do some clean up when an asynchronous operation completed.  Is there an important difference between calling a member function in this way?  Why would I choose the first example over the second?

Take these two examples:

```
someAsyncOperation.apply(foo).whenComplete(MyClass::handleOperationCompletion);
```

Versus:

```
someAsyncOperation.apply(foo).whenComplete((results, ex) -> handleOperationCompletion(results, ex));
```

Calling the static function, from an anonymous function, let's me add additional arguments in the local scope.  In this second case I could add a local variable:

```
final Closeable object = new SomeCloseable();
someAsyncOperation.apply(foo).whenComplete((results, ex) -> handleOperationCompletion(results, ex, object));
```

I feel like this could be useful if I need keep context on some object to perform clean up (e.g like close a stream), and I can still write unit tests for it. Is there a trade off I'm missing here?

Comment: Looks like you're debating between member methods and static methods - what does it have to do with anonymous class ? and yes, static is bad for testing.

Comment: Lambda function = anonymous function = "(results, ex) -> handleOperationCompletion(results, ex, object)"  I'm debating between using that pattern or: " MyClass::handleOperationCompletion"  Apologies.  If this isn't clear I'll try to update the question.

Comment: See duplicate for an answer straight from the horse's mouth.

Comment: Inside `whenComplete` you're calling `handleOperationCompletion` once as a static method and the other option is as a member method. The fact that it's wrapped with lambda is just a technical detail but I don't see how it affects anything. So after all it looks like you're debating between making a method static or not...